# Can Behat be set never to reset browser cookies? Just behave as normal manual browser session?

Tags: cookies, behat

I've got an issue that looks like it's linked with cookies being lost during a scenario test.

The scenario flow looks a bit like:

```
Create a new user

login

Do some stuff

Click a link aiming to do more stuff

result: Login page unexpectedly shown (does not happen if manually carrying out same actions)
```

To troubleshoot the above, whilst I'm getting used to testing with Behat, I would really like for behat instigated browser sessions to behave like normal, in terms of keeping a session alive between browser starts, and not wiping down cookies from a previous test run.

For example:

```
Create a new user and login

Do some stuff

Exit the browser

Open the browser

Go to website URL
```

Website generally continues from where you left off, ie, you're still logged in.

Is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know when using @insulated tag each scenario will have a clean browser.
If you are using this tag then remove it an see if is working.

Be aware that this is not a good practice at all since each scenario should be independent.

You should not rely on a previous scenario since is possible to fail and affect all following scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although my test scenario at present is not running with any tags, so I guess by default it is being run as insulated.